# Open specific link in browser, but not in WebView - Eclipse Android

Tags: android

I created an app for my website: when I open the app it shows me my site in WebView and all links in my site also open in WebView. But there is a button on the site with a link that looks like "http://www.domain.com/out/some-text". If someone clicks on this link, the link should open in the default browser of Android and not in WebView.

Here is the code:

```
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

WebView web;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
// Inflate the menu
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
           return true;
        }

        // Handle click events
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.add:
              Toast.makeText(this, "Android App V1.1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
           case R.id.help:
               finish();
               System.exit(0);
              return true;

           default:
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        }
}
```

How can I do that?

THx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

Into "shouldOverrideUrlLoading".

Comment: But I think this will not open the link www.domain.com/out/some-text in the defautl browser. All other links should open in WebView, only this link in the browser.

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve the problem...it will open all links in the browser. This would be fine, however, if the specific link has a static URL and you can just check to see if the URL in shoudlOverrideUrlLoading is equal to it, then make this call.